# HTML 5 web sockets and XMPP Server dialog

Tags: sockets, xmpp

Does using web sockets actually mean browsers will be able communicate with xmpp servers (any other IM servers) directly ?

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

No. Allowing TCP-level access to arbitrary servers would cause all kinds of security problems. Imagine a website which caused every user to connect to an SMTP server and start sending spam emails… suddenly you have a massively distributed spam attack, especially if combined with an XSS attack on a major site. Web Sockets has a small amount of framing around it designed to make such attacks impossible, without adding too much overhead over TCP.

Answer (score 0):

One day.  It's likely that we'll define an XMPP sub-protocol for websockets that can replace BOSH([XEP-0124](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html)/[0206](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html)) when both the client and server support it.  In the meantime, BOSH is widely implemented.

Answer (score 0):

you can think of HTTP polling ....
and transfer xmpp data along 8080 port..